# NLTK TweetTokenizer not working (Python)

Tags: python, nltk

I have currently installed NLTK and have run the command `nltk.download()`. However not all the libraries are installed (it gets stuck on panlex_lite).

The thing is that when I try to import Tweet Tokenizer I get the error:

> File "create_docs.py", line 7, in
>
> ```
> from nltk.tokenize import TweetTokenizer ImportError: cannot import
> ```
>
> name TweetTokenizer

How can I deal with this? Cheers!

Comment: have you tried nltk.download('panlex_lite') ?

Comment: @sb0709, yes it prints: `[nltk_data] Downloading package panlex_lite to
[nltk_data]     /home/vladimir/nltk_data...
` But it won't finish.

Answer (score 0):

This is because is not installed properly libraries, so need to skip *"panlex_lite"* libraries and should work.

> Currently is open issue for this, solution will be as follow:

```
I guess, we could add something like if id != 'panlex_lite' to the code...

But, as for me, the easiest way looks like this:

get https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nltk/nltk_data/gh-pages/index.xml
remove panlex from it
upload it to a public Gist
pass the gist's url to the downloader: python -m nltk.downloader -d /usr/local/share/nltk_data -u https://gist.githubusercontent.com/demidovakatya/61dab385d74065ae825c80496a197980/raw/c6ff7fbf44265c7f8c9e961e3e1158cd812d6af1/index.xml all
```

here is the link to issue: [look at last 2 conversations](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/1338)